# android toolbar like facebook or gmail app

Tags: android

i need the same thing like the toolbar on the Facebook or gmail App (i also want it do disappear when scrolling down and appear when scrolled on top again)

The thing is, im using a ActionBar on the top of the App already, what i need is another toolbar on the bottom. I thought about using the new toolbar and place it on the bottom(is this possbile? i mean using ActionBar and toolbar? If yes can i place it on the bottom?

I also tried to add more buttons in my ActionBar and put splitWhenNarrow in my manifest but it doesnt work..it just gets "scrollable" icons :S
Heres how i tried it :

```
<activity
    android:name="com.danny.pqapp."
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/pqBlue">
<meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
    android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</activity>
```

anyone has an idea how to solve my problem?